MAUI raises an error in Apple when using AppCenter
In my NET8 MAUI app, I'm using AppCenter. I noticed that AppCenter raises a few errors when the app runs on iOS. Here the errors:

2024-05-24 10:08:25.085720+0100 LanguageInUse[10807:123861] Task
<44699F05-B2FF-4151-B525-5430CEC98ED4>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes
(error code: -1001 [1:60])
2024-05-24 10:08:25.097346+0100
LanguageInUse[10807:123861] Task
<44699F05-B2FF-4151-B525-5430CEC98ED4>.<1> finished with error [-1001]
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000004a7b40
{Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied),
interface: en1[802.11], uses wifi, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60,
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask
<44699F05-B2FF-4151-B525-5430CEC98ED4>.<1>,
_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <44699F05-B2FF-4151-B525-5430CEC98ED4>.<1>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://in.appcenter.ms/logs?api-version=1.0.0,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://in.appcenter.ms/logs?api-version=1.0.0,
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2024-05-24 10:08:25.110523+0100 LanguageInUse[10807:124203] [AppCenter] ERROR: -[MSACHttpClient
requestCompletedWithHttpCall:data:response:error:]/151 HTTP request
error with code: -1001, domain: NSURLErrorDomain, description: The
request timed out. 2024-05-24 10:08:25.110897+0100
LanguageInUse[10807:124203] [AppCenter] ERROR:
-[MSACChannelUnitDefault sendLogContainer:]_block_invoke/233 Log(s) sent with failure, batch Id:E48FF504-C463-43F6-951F-7F1BA3D6F0E0,
status code:0

I know AppCenter will be retired new year but I didn't want to change it now. Do you know if there is a way to fix those issues or I must remove AppCenter for my app?

These look like pretty benign log messages.  Unless they are actually causing a problem I would ignore them

AppCenter is gonna sunset in a year even if this is a real issue it will not be addressed
